# On the use of \color in equations

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I recently see more and more people utilize the `\color` function to make equations easier to understand, e.g.:

$$\frac{3\color{blue}{x}}{4}\times\frac{42}{\color{blue}{x}} = \frac{3\times 42}{4}=\frac{63}{2}$$

However, I would like to remind you that there are about $5\%$ of the population which suffer from one or another form of color-blindness. To me the colors are often confusing and sometimes even cause a notable eye-strain when trying to understand what is written.

It is impossible to meet the needs of all the different people with their different deficiencies, so instead I will make the following appeal:

**Please**, if you think about using colors - think about using `\mathbf`, `\mathit` or `\underline` first. Try not to overdo the colors, too.

Comment: I definitely agree with the sentiment, but doesn't much of this come down to the difference between using color for content and using color for emphasis?  I would think most people would be fine with your example even in the absence of color, for instance, since the color here serves to emphasize but not to define anything; where color is an essential part of the answer then it ought to be treated much more carefully...

Comment: @Steven: Unless the question is about the color, I don't see how it is essential for the content. On the other hand, I have made several remarks which were later incorporated as edits, about this very thing. I figured pointing this out in a meta thread might make it easier for me in the future.

Comment: I also have to wonder if whoever downvoted this also boycotts any handicap accessible business place...

Comment: Did it occur to you that someone might downvote who has his own troubles parsing content and feels greatly helped by color? I certainly did not downvote this and I will take your problem into account in the future, but as you say yourself, it is not possible to meet the needs of everyone, so ... you expect that *you* should be accommodated. Assigning anti-handicapped people motives to downvoters is unwarranted.

Comment: @Phira: Yes, it has occurred to me. However seeing how until recently there was a very scarce use of color on the site, but there was still a lot of content going on... I don't see any actual basis for your argument. It is a reasonable one, though.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your argument, but it looks like you're saying that the removing of the color annotations in your example, _without doing anything else_, would be an improvement to the post. That sounds backwards -- in my view color that is not essential for the message is an _appropriate_ use of color. It's a bonus that doesn't detract from the experience of people who can't see it. In contrast, it would be a problem if the use of color was _essential_ to understand what the author meant.

Comment: @Henning: Well, my eyes have difficulties with red and green and the light colors (yellow, for example) make them hurt badly due to the contrast with other colors around. On the other hand, another person might have severe problems with blue and purple (and if you put those together I will have a problem as well). If one color (other than black) is enough, my request is merely to use that. If no, my request is to try and see boldface and italics as means to an end -- before starting with the different colors.

Comment: And as with Phira's comment I should add: content was here before colored posts were common.

Comment: Do you experience eye strain when viewing (colored) images?

Comment: @TheChaz: It depends on the colors involved. Bright colors on white often do that, while on a different background they might not cause that.

Comment: Presumably there are already ways for color-challenged folks to force monochrome rendering. If your argument held weight, the entire web would be monochrome. I use colors when they greatly aid discerning structure. I encourage everyone to do so in such contexts.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I agree that color may sometimes aid. I *completely* disagree with several of your conclusions: (1) not all color-blinded folks "prefer" monochromatic view, certainly not someone with an extremely atypical C.B. like myself; (2) note that most textual content on the web - at least on sites which tend to be serious - is limited to a rather small amount of colors. It is also worth mentioning that many places on the web have a slightly darker background which allows bright colors to be used as well. If I have to guess, you are not a color blind, am I right?

Comment: I should also point out that even looking at my own coloring in the original post my eyes get confused and the letters close to the blue ones lose their blackness and turn into some dark brown-red sort of shade, which funnily enough causes the blue have some (extremely) slight purplish hue. Yes, having my color vision can mimic the effects of hallucinogenics sometimes. It can be quite fun and quite annoying!

Comment: @AsafKaragila makes a very good point, and those of us who are teachers should bear it in mind in the classroom as well, I think, when choosing how to make slides for example.

Comment: @Asaf This problem appears to be easily solvable. Simply configure your MathJax environment so that \color does nothing. I'm sure there are MathJax wizards who would be happy to assist you.

Comment: @Bill: So your suggestion is for people with a minor limp to simply never walk on their feet again and stick to wheelchairs?

Comment: @Asaf Of course one can do smarter things too, such as mapping the $\LaTeX$ colorspace into one that works for you. There are many solutions that do not involve throwing out the baby with the bath water.

Comment: @Bill: I did not ask anyone *not* to use colors. I merely requested that upon using them, one  should think about *all* viewers and not just themselves. So if boldface or underlining has the same discerning effect as colors, I don't see why you insist on making the post **unreadable** or worse (it can in fact become indiscernible!) for some of your readers.

Comment: I personally have no problem with color vision, but I think the color posts look extremely ugly. Personally, I think they are annoying as the blink tag in HTML.

Comment: @Asaf Even if all of our users, current and future, were aware of these issues, and did their best to help, it probably would help little, since most folks have little knowledge of the complex design decisions needed to address such issues. But since we cannot even get folks to read the FAQ, there's little chance of teaching them about such. If you really desire to solve it once and for all then your best bet is to do as I suggest, and force the changes you desire via software mods on your end.

Comment: @Bill: Unfortunately this is impossible, my color blindness is *very* atypical and none of the standard modifications are close to my deficiency. The result is that it looks bad no matter what I try, so I stick with the original. On the other hand, since most of the users that I saw are also meta readers I would think that a meta thread which merely tries to raise *some* awareness was in order. In fact, it is not the software design which I am worried about. (...)

Comment: (...) Much like there is nothing in the software design to explain inverse limits to a logician, there is nothing in the software design to help a color-blinded man discern and read the equations properly. On the other hand, the human factor of the site **can** explain inverse limits to a logician, and **can** take into consideration the choice of colors and the alternative (or even additional) use of boldface fonts.

Comment: @Asaf So how would you propose to modify the color emphasis in the multiplicative telescopic cancellation in my [post here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143539/242)

Comment: @Asaf But what about my prior suggestion of taking complete control in MathJax of the $\LaTeX$ colorspace? Presumably that will enable you to remap the colors into colors that do not cause problems for you.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, your post is a good example for when colors are definitely better than boldface (although even without *all* these colors, the message is crystal clear and perfectly readable.) I would suggest to keep some distance between red and green (esp. in $\frac{g(n-1)}{g(n-2)}$). I also don't see how "a complete control over the colorspace" would help me. Sitting through and tweaking  the colors to fit *my* vision is an arduous task. Far far harder than the few seconds required for a person fully aware to this problem to rethink colors vs. boldface issues.

Comment: @Asaf But tweaking the colorspace need be done only once, and it can be done optimally for your needs. I do analogous things all the time, e.g. being an Emacs developer, I heavily tweaked the Gnus newsreader to suit my preferences (not only for colors, but for scoring, and many other things). If you're not already a software developer, it's not hard to get up to speed for simple mods, esp. with expert coding knowledge at your fingertips via the stackexchange sites, one can go very far quite quickly.

Comment: @Bill: I have minor experience in software development, and I suppose I should thank you for the period I used common lisp and became an emacs fan (although nano is better for simple tasks). The problem is not in the software, though. It is in the actual tweaking, it is in the actual colors I will choose, that when the light is slightly different may become problematic again; when several different colors are combined my eye sight will try to compensate and once again the chosen palette will be wrong. **These** reasons are the source of the problem.

Comment: @Bill: I don't mind reciprocating. Once during my army service (I was a sysadmin) me and my commander were working on some Excel table presenting statistical data which we were requested to generate. He went to get something to drink and asked me to set the colors of the table. Upon returning a few minutes later he was shocked and since then no one has requested me to do any color related work. I could write a few equations using the colors I see fit, but I can assure you that it is unlikely your eyes will be happy about it.

Comment: @Asaf Interesting. Should you decide to attempt software mods, then I'll be happy to offer my help. I'm sure others would to. I suspect we have a fair amount of software expertise in our community.

Comment: This needs more development before it's a solution: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/efeladnkafmoofnbagdbfaieabmejfcf. I find the color to be quite helpful, and I often wonder why examples are limited to black and white in a situation where the cost of color ink is not really a factor. Admittedly, the extension needs a lot of work, and in particular I think it is currently restricted to images and not text, but there have been other extensions (like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorblindext/?src=search) which handled both, and got rave reviews from colorblind users.

Comment: @MichaelBoratko: I use Firefox, however the add on you suggest is for version 2.0x and not for Linux/FF12. I recall using it a few years ago and not being too impressed. There are currently two other add ons for Firefox, both *completely* useless for me. The first can simply be configured to strip color tags; the second has profiles set for the three common color deficiencies and neither matches my eyesight.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am sorry. I downvoted your question, but I've never "boycott(ed) any handicap accessible business place...". I am ready to undo my downvote. However, now I cannot do that, unless you make some trivial edit for that purpose only. I don't know whether  that's possible via any of the moderators.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. I've already undone my downvote.

Comment: I upvoted, because I also agree.

Comment: @Asaf: I'm sorry to hear about your CB. As for me, I'm fond of using colors in my beamer presentations but never used them in answers on MSE (perhaps, never wrote an answer where it would be of help). Indeed, the first impression of your post was that you encourage others *not* to use colouring (which I would dislike) but in the case you only ask people not to use colours whenever alternatives might work as well, please take my upvote. I also agree that those who use colouring on MSE are aware of existence of Meta and hence it's likely they'll see your post.

Comment: I use colors when I think it helps, and I also find special fonts features troublesome: underlining is unreadable with fractions and italics or bold might be unnoticed or taken as a mistake/typo. However, I understand this issue and indeed I would love to have commands like `\distinguish{k}{text}` which **reader** could customize in his profile: some would pick colors, others would pick font-features.

Comment: I am quite shocked that none of you even considered posting alternative answers in Braille, this is obvious discrimination against blind mathematicians.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: While obviously sarcastic, blind people have screen readers to begin with. Color blind people, and in particular atypical CB like myself, have nothing but the good faith of the users to avoid extreme colors.

Comment: Asaf, would the first suggestion I made in a comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/175349/5363) (using `\color{#xC00}{...}`) be problematic for you to read and cause eye-strain?

Comment: @t.b.: It's not easy to discern these shades on my monitor and it took me a whole minute of intense comparisons to locate the colored parts on my iPhone (I opened it on the computer only later, so I knew what to look for) I think that boldface would have worked **much** better, and if not that then probably a color code `#0C0` rather than `#C00` would be better.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and I'll use boldface in the future. Nevertheless, it is somewhat surprising to me because `#C00` looks much more neutral to my eyes than `#0C0`... How about a bluish shade like `#00C`? Is that better or worse than `#0C0`?

Comment: @t.b. Doh!. I meant bluish, not greenish. I counted R-G-B wrong as R-B-G... :-D

Comment: Thanks again. You seem to have a tendency of messing up the order of letters these days :)

Comment: @t.b. Yes, I thought so as well. Maybe I'm not drinking enough...

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila very very smart

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment of making things easy to read for the colourblind, I strongly disagree with the proposed solution. For me, $x$, $\mathrm{x}$, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\underline{x}$ are all different symbols, and using them as if they were synonyms would be confusing and - in a way - ungramatical. (Often, $\mathbf{x}$ would be a vector, $\underline{x}$ would be a sequence, the mathrm font signifies that ``these are letters, not variables'', as in $\mathrm{lim} f(x)$.). The reason why colour is so useful is that it impossible to use consistently, so it didn't get assigned any meaning!

Comment: @Jakub: So I take it that you never gave a lecture with only one color of chalk/marker. Because how would you emphasize something on the board in that case?

Comment: @Asaf: 1. OK, I'm overexaggerating slightly. 2. During a lecture I have a lot of options to emphasise whatever I need: apart of just saying so, or physically pointing at something, I can circle it or put it in a box, draw an arrow pointing to it, possibly underline it, etc. Using italics and bold fonts would be impractical during the lecture anyways. 3. My point is *not* that colour is the only acceptable way to add emphasis, but rather that I'm not a fan of the ones proposed. I'm all in favour of placing things in boxes, using underbraces, etc.

Comment: @Jakub: $\fbox{You can draw boxes.}$ You don't have to resort to boldface etc., I only gave *some* possible solutions. Not a complete enumeration of all them. And all I did was ask people to consider such alternatives to coloring, especially when using *more* than two color (black and an additional color).

Comment: It's worth noting that when color is used in a post, it may begin as something not essential to content. But then the subsequent comments and answers may directly refer to "the quantities in blue" or whatever. And then the color becomes essential to content despite the original poster's message. So for each comment here about color being used to emphasize something and not being essential to the message, there is still more to think about.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I'm sure that these comments could have addressed "the third equation", or "the second fraction of the third equation". Just like I got a referee report with very specific references to stuff I wrote, even though no color was used anywhere!

Answer (score 30):

I have made an [extension](http://www.math.union.edu/locate/Cervone/transfer/mathjax/mathjax-MSE-color-ignore.user.js) that eliminates all color styling from MathJax output.  It should work in all the major browsers, though some need plug-ins to handle it; see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates) for links to those.  For IE, you will need to download the file and change the name so that it ends in `.ieuser.js` rather then `.user.js` before the plugin will recognize it as a user script (silly but true).

It would be possible to make a similar extension that exchanges one color for another, but I don't really know what the right colors are that would be good for the visually challenged.  A more sophisticated version would exchange ranges of colors based on their RGB or HLS or other color-space values.

Personally, I find that people use colors that are too saturated, and I think it helps to use less saturated versions.  For example, I find $\color{#C00}{\rm\#C00}$ easier to read than $\color{red}{\rm RED}$, at least on a white background.

Anyway, hope this is useful.  If anyone wants to suggest what would be appropriate for a color-exchanging extension to do, I might be able to come up with something for that.

Comment: That is **awesome**. I'll give it a spin later today.

Comment: ${\color{Blue} T}{\color{Red} h}{\color{Green} a}{\color{DarkOrange} n}{\color{Yellow} k}{\color{Teal} s}!$

Comment: @Davide How can one obtain such colors in MathJax? Doesn't definition of colors require some color libraries that aren't defaultly loaded?

Comment: @BillDubuque, no, MathJax's default `\color` macro allows you to use any valid HTML color value.  So `\color{#C00}{x+1}` produces $\color{#C00}{x+1}$.  (The default `\color` macro doesn't work the same as the $\rm\LaTeX$ one; if you want the $\rm\LaTeX$-compatible version, then you do need to load an extension).

Comment: @Davide Thanks, that good to know. I had presumed it worked only with the named colors, not having seen any other usage. Perhaps I should really read the code. Where can it be found?

Comment: @BillDubuque, the MathJax code is on GitHub at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/ but you should look in the "unpacked' directory for readable code.

Comment: The link just outputs the JS code, shouldn't the extension of the file be `.user.js` rather than just `.js` for GM to identify this as a script?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks, you are right.  I have fixed the link and the name on the server.  How embarassing!

Comment: @DavideCervone How does one download extensions for MathJax and use them on the site?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, if you mean the extension that I created, you need a tool like [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net) in order to use files that end in `.user.js`.  If you install the TamperMonkey plugin, then when you click on the link above, it should ask if you want to install the extension, and it should work automatically after you do.  The extension has a control pane that lets you turn its extensions on and off.

Answer (score 26):

[*Update:*] This answer refers to the initial version of Bill's arguments in the comments. By the time I had posted this, Bill had already made a less extreme point about tweaking colour rendering rather than turning it off. I don't have enough experience with that to weigh in on the difference of opinion between Bill and Asaf about whether this would be an efficient solution of the problem.

---

I'm disappointed that four people downvoted this question, most of them apparently without making any constructive suggestions. All the more so because Asaf was merely alerting us to a problem and making a reasonable appeal to consider alternatives, not asking anyone not to use colours. If, as Phira suggests, people downvoted because they have trouble reading stuff emphasized by bold/italic/underline instead, then they should say so, so that we can find the best solution for everyone. So far, no-one has said so, and as long as no-one does, Asaf's suggestion seems like a good solution to me. I doubt that forcing monochrome rendering, as Bill suggested, is a solution, since it would turn off *all* colours, including in graphs etc., where content might not make sense without them, e.g. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143380/inverse-josephus-problem/143421#143421) I gave today. I also don't see any contradiction between Bill's announcement that he will use colours when they "greatly aid discerning structure" and Asaf's appeal to consider alternatives, if "greatly aid" is interpreted as "aid more greatly than the alternatives without colour".

So I would ask everyone to take Asaf's appeal seriously, and then if you've considered the alternatives and still feel that those who can discern colours would benefit significantly more from your post if you add them, then by all means add them.

Comment: Please note that I suggested to *remap* the colorspace. This includes various possibilities, both monochrome and multichrome. It would be interesting to know the reasons for the downvotes. Perhaps they simple boil down to, as Paul Simon sang "Mama, don't take my Kodachrome away". We need a new verse: MathJax, don't crash my bloated Chrome today!

Comment: @Bill: :-) Yes, I saw your more detailed comments only after I posted the answer; the first one was only about forcing monochrome rendering.

Comment: I would like to thank you, I feel that without your answer more people would probably have misread and misunderstood me.

Comment: @joriki Could you please be so kind to update your answer to reflect more accurately what I wrote. Note that my comment about remapping the colorspace was in fact posted a half hour before your answer was posted.

Comment: I misread and misunderstood you, Asaf, and voted accordingly. The inflammatory comments about boycotts and limps/wheelchairs didn't do much to win me over, but joriki helped me to see it in a new light. Since the edit, I have changed my vote.

Comment: Again, it would be great if people could explain their downvotes. If they're because of my representation of @Bill's argument, please note that it correctly represented his argument up to a certain point. That I didn't reload the comments before posting and that Bill later made a better argument doesn't mean that I was misrepresenting him; the argument as I represented it was in fact all of what was there for a certain time. I'm updating the answer now.

Comment: @Bill: I hope I've now represented the final form of your arguments more faithfully. You're right that I could have reloaded the comments before posting, but on the other hand, if you want to avoid your arguments being represented in a certain form, you shouldn't let them stand in that form before making more subtle points.

Comment: @joriki I'm puzzled by your remark. It's only natural to propose simpler solutions first. As soon as Asaf made it clear that his problem was more complex, I proposed the remapping approach. Only 8 minutes passed between the two proposals. An additional 28 minutes passed before your answer was posted. Were I following an ongoing discussion, then before criticizing the viewpoint of another, I would be sure to be uptodate on the discussion. And when informed of a misunderstanding, I would fix it asap, not two days later. Else one risks coming across as purposely misrepresenting another.

Comment: (Wasn't me *this time*!)

Comment: @Bill: a) I'm sorry it took me two days to update the post. b) I'd already acknowledged that it would have been better had I updated the comments before posting. That's a mistake on quite a different scale than purposely misrepresenting someone. c) The "risk" of coming across as purposely misrepresenting someone wasn't as impersonal as you describe it; it came about because your comments created the impression that I was misrepresenting you. I still feel that I accurately described a certain state of the debate, then $47$ minutes later acknowledged in a comment that the debate had moved on.

Comment: @joriki Could you please remove any mention of my name from your answer. Then we can remove these comments. I don't understand why it is so difficult for you to comprehend what I write, but my patience is quite exhausted.

Comment: @Bill: I don't like that combative style. I'm not going to do anything of the sort. This is a public record.

Comment: @Bill: I moved the update to the top to make sure that no-one reads the rest without reading it. As far as I can tell that should take care of any issues of "misrepresentation".

Comment: @joriki Again you baffle me. "Combative style"??? I hinted and asked (quite politely) for what I thought would be a simple gracious edit. Were I in your position, I would have quickly apologized for any misunderstanding. And if I lacked the time to edit the answer, I would have told you to feel free to do so. That would have avoided any friction, and resolved the matter quite quickly. But, alas, that's not what occurred. Now the mattter is completely blown out of proportion.